# SQL JOIN and ORDER two tables by one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I've got two SQL tables, `Activity` and `Notifications`, and on the client end I have a view that displays an amalgamation of both. However, this view needs to be paginated (the average user likely has 100s of objects here) and sorted by the `createdAt` column, which both tables have.

How can I write an SQL query to JOIN both tables vertically, sort by `createdAt`, and lastly limit/offset?

EDIT:

Schema:

`Activity(id, createdAt, media, userId)`

`Notifications(id, createdAt, userId, text)`

Expected Result (createdAt in descending order):

```
id | createdAt | media | userId | text
---------------------------------------
1  | ...       | t.jpg | 56     | null
...
10 | ...       | null  | 45     | test
```

Comment: Can you put table schema and expected result in question ?

Comment: Can you also add which DB server you are using so we can ensure the syntax is correct.

Comment: PostgreSQL, schema coming up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at your example it seems that you need to union the tables:

```
select id, createdAt, media, userId, Null as text from Activity 
union all
select id, createdAt, Null as media, userId, text from Notifications 
order by createdAt
limit 100
```

Comment: Ah yes UNION. That's what I was looking for

Comment: Is there a way to include all fields in a UNION without manually entering each?

Comment: the problem is that for UNION to work the fields in both selects should match in number and type. In your case you have some fields in one table that don't appear in the other so you need to include Nulls. The first select could be select Activity.*, Null  but the other one has the Null in between fields so you have to explicitly include them all.